# Choosing frameworks for creating the platform for students

Tags: reactjs, django, frameworks

I wanna create a platform as a project for my university.
Here are main features:

- the teacher can create tests and run them at specific times
- students are limited in time and can pass tests (each test has got it's own time limit)
- there is an overall student ranking on the home page
- the teacher can publish the homework

What should I choose?
I am thinking about Django + React/Angular.
What would you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are familiar with React/Angular, Django + DRF(django-rest-framework) for the REST API and React/Angular for the web page would be a good combo.

Or just using Django you can easily create all the functionality you mentioned.